# How to know if app performance is good in expo performance screen?

Tags: react-native, expo

Expo performance monitor keeps increasing the dropped frames every few seconds, is it normal? What's the maximum dropped frames that mean there's a problem in the app?

Answer (score 0):

If frame rate (FPS) is increasing its good, don't worry about it.

**Expo performance:**

- RAM usage of your project
- JavaScript heap (this is an easy way to know of any memory leaks in your application)
- 2 numbers for Views, the top indicates the number of views for the screen, the bottom indicates the number of views in the component
- Frames Per Second for the UI and JS threads. The UI thread is used for native Android or iOS UI rendering. The JS thread is where most of your logic will be run, including API calls, touch events, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually asking about the "dropped frames" it's increasing, what does it mean?